# Replicating Good Seasons brand Italian salad dressing dry mix

Tags: spices, restaurant-mimicry, salad-dressing

I use the dry mix in a ranch chicken recipe. I would like to make my own version from scratch. How would I go about trying to duplicate there recipe so to speak? I've looked at the list of ingredients on the package but I don't know what actually makes the flavor, and what is preservatives.

Ingredients: sugar, salt, sodium, citrate, garlic, onions, spice, red bell peppers, carrots, xanthan gum, maltodextrin, parsley, guar gum, natural flavor, soy sauce (wheat, soybeans, salt), citric acid,

Comment: There are lots of recipes for "homemade dry ranch dressing mix" like [this one](http://www.simplyscratch.com/2014/05/homemade-ranch-dressing-mix.html). I recommend you start there. We can certainly help you mimic a powder you like but that would require that you post the brand and ingredients specifically so that we can help with that. If you're just looking for any old recipe, we don't do recipe requests, but you should have no trouble finding one. My [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=homemade+dry+ranch+dressing+mix&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) search turned up dozens.

Comment: Wait... are you looking for Ranch dressing or Italian? Your title says "Italian" but your recipe is "ranch chicken".... [here's a recipe](http://www.epicurious.com/recipes/member/views/homemade-good-seasons-italian-dressing-mix-50049303) for Italian, if that's what you need instead,

Comment: I was meaning the Italian version. Sorry for not making that clear.

Comment: The ingredient list you provided says "dried" at the end - something's missing, I'm guessing?

Comment: @Jefromi - Nope. Looking at the image in the history, "dried" has an asterisk and indicates some ingredients are dried. I'll just remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Classically a Italian blend would be:

```
teaspoon dried thyme 
teaspoon dried basil 
tablespoon dried parsley
tablespoon garlic salt 
tablespoon onion powder  
tablespoon white sugar 
tablespoons dried oregano 
teaspoon ground black pepper 
teaspoon celery salt
teaspoon salt
```

The just add water/oil/vinegar to make into dressing.